# Equivalent of maven archetype for sbt

Tags: scala, maven, build, sbt, maven-archetype

Does sbt (Scala build tool) have the concept of archetypes, similar to the way that you can define an archetype in a maven project? Basically a blueprint for a new project that might have specific dependencies already defined for you, or perhaps some prebuilt classes and traits?

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, in sbt, we can use other plugins to achiecve this. [**sbt-native-packager**](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/introduction.html) can be used. As quoted in its documentation:

> SBT native packager lets you build application packages in native
>   formats and offers different archetypes for common configurations,
>   such as simple Java apps or server applications

Let me know if it helps!!

.